# jQuery - Adding classes to elements inside array with delay

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I have an array that contains some elements from my page.

Now I need a function that literates through the array and adds a class `bold` to each element. The problem is that once the class is added, some time has to pass. Then `bold` has to be removed and needs to be applied to the next element, resulting in a "wave" motion.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
$.each(tdArr, function(i, v) {
  v.addClass("bold");
  setTimeout(function(){
    v.removeClass("bold");
  }, 900)
})
```

The problem with that code is that `bold` is added to *all* elements at once and gets removed 900 ms later, again from *all* elements at the same time.

What do I have to do to add a delay between the separate actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to approach this slightly differently, as `setTimout` returns straight away it wont stop the next element being set as bold.

You could do it with a method like this:

```
function bold(i){
    if(i>0){
        $tdArr.eq(i-1).removeClass('bold');
    }
    if(i == $tdArr.length){
        return;
    }
    $tdArr.eq(i).addClass('bold')   

    setTimeout(function() { bold(i+1) },900);
}
```

And then to call it you'd just need to call `bold(0)`:

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/rJGjZ/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(tdArr, function(index, element) {
  var $elem = $(element);
  $elem.addClass("bold");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $elem.removeClass("bold");
  }, 900)
})
```

The second param is not a jQuery element and you need convert him

Answer (score 0):

Increase the delay as you iterate the array, and make sure to wrap your element in jQuery if it's not already wrapped. If it's a collection of jQuery elements, then use `each` to iterate.

```
var delay = 900

$els.each(function(){
  var $this = $(this)
  setTimeout(function(){
    $els.removeClass('bold')
    $this.addClass('bold')
  }, delay+=900)
})
```

Otherwise, I would use `for` and wrap the element in jQuery.

```
for (var i=0, l=arr.length, d, prev; i<l; i++; d+=900) {
  prev = arr[i-1]
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (prev) $(prev).removeClass('bold')
    $(arr[i]).addClass('bold')
  }, d)
}
```

Comment: This would work, except the `$(this)` inside the timeout refers to the function itself, not the jQuery object as part of the `each`. Just pu tthe following above the `setTimeout`: `var $this = $(this);` and use `$this` inside. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/hUeK4/

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you ?

```
function Bold(element) {
  $(element).addClass("bold"); // we bold the current tdArr
  setTimeout(function(){
    var nextSibling = $(element).next("td") // (if the tdArr are "td" tags) we find the next td brother of this one
    if (!!nextSibling) Bold(nextSibling); // if there is a brother, repeat the function on him after 900ms
  }, 900)
}

Bold(myfirsttd);
```

Comment: Since you've a jQuery selector to get your elements, you can apply a function like that one. Just change the selectors. It justs need the 1st element and then find the siblings