# jquery add class to multiple elements with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 3 div elements with class name `gridbox`
i want to add a class into all 3 elements with delay.

**for example:**

new class should be added to all 3 div elements with a delay between each of them.

i triel following code which is not working.

```
$('.gridbox').addClass('animation').delay(1500);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: see this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797668/jquery-adding-classes-to-elements-inside-array-with-delay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var divs = $( '.gridbox' );
var index = 0;

var delay = setInterval( function(){
  if ( index <= divs.length ){
    $( divs[ index ] ).addClass( 'animation' );
    index += 1;
  }else{
    clearInterval( delay );
  }
}, 1500 );
```

What I'm doing here is this:

1. Extract all of the elements and store them in the `divs` variable.
2. Save an index of the element you are currently working with.
3. Initiate a `setTimeout` function with a delay of 1.5 seconds.
4. If we are not at the end of the list of elements, add the class to the relevant element after converting it to a jQuery element.
5. Increment our index variable.
6. Stop the setTimeout once we have iterated over all of the elements.

Comment: And I assume `divs[ index ]` returns a native DOM element, which has no method addClass, so this fails until you start using `eq()` etc

Comment: @adeneo - very true - thanks for that! I'll make the appropriate edits.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.gridbox').each(function(i) {
    (function(self, j) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(self).addClass('animation');
        },(j*1500)+1500);
    })(this, i);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4jbS/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try combination of [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and `setTimeout`

```
$('.gridbox').each(function (index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.addClass('animation');
    }, 1500 * index );
});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EL55C/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.gridbox').each(function(index) {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(that).addClass('animation');
  }, 1500 * index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply a delay on a jquery function such as addClass you need to use a javascript setTimeout because as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) `.delay()` is limited and should be used for jQuery effects

Answer (score 0):

a nicer solution :)

```
var st = setInterval(function(){
    var gb = $('.gridbox:not(.animation):eq(0)');
    gb.length > 0 ? gb.addClass('animation') : clearInterval(st);
},1500)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jR984/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without jQuery

```
function addClass () {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName("aaa");
  div[0].className = "bbb";
  setTimeout(addClass, 1000);
}
window.onload = function () {
  addClass();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/khGCv/

Answer (score 0):

Although setTimeout/Interval kinda "works", jquery provides a much cleaner way to do custom animations: [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), for example:

```
$(".gridbox").each(function() {
    var box = this;
    $("body").queue(function(next) {
        $(box).addClass("animation");
        next();
    }).delay(1000)
});
```